# For loop error when Json key is replaced by an other one

Tags: python, json

I've made a for loop to find keys in a Json file, I've got an issue when the `price` key is replaced by 'price_calendar' key.
It appears when the customer doesn't put price in his ad.
I'm tring to go over this error with an if statement but it doesn't work.
If anyone can explain why it doesn't work.

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, 
data=json.dumps(payload))
status = response.status_code
result = response.json()
ads = result['ads']

for ad in ads: 
  id = ad['list_id']
  print(id)
  title = ad['subject']
  print(title)
  url = ad['url']
  print(url)
  if ad['price'][0] not in ads:
    print ('No price')
  else:
    price = ad['price'][0]
    print (price,"$")
  date = ad['first_publication_date']
  print(date)
```

---

Error :

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError 'price'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check existence of key in dict you are looking value based on that key

you shouldn't override build in `id()` function

```
for ad in ads: 
  id = ad['list_id']
  print(id)
  title = ad['subject']
  print(title)
  url = ad['url']
  print(url)

  #if 'price' not in ad.keys() or ad['price'][0] not in ads:
  #    print ('No price')
```

changed due to task context where question owner wants only to check if price is in dict keys

```
  if 'price' not in ad.keys():
    print ('No price')

  else:
    price = ad['price'][0]
    print (price,"$")
  date = ad['first_publication_date']
  print(date)
```

Comment: When I try your code, It almost works but this code go trough the if statement and put ('no price') on each ads.
It works when I change your if statement by this :  if 'price' not in ad.keys():  print ('No price')
Thanks a lot

Comment: no problem remember to rename id value for something not overriding build-in functions

Answer (score 0):

```
if ad['price'][0] not in ads:
```

already looks up `ad['price']`, so if there is no `price` at all in the dictionary, `ad['price']` won't be valid and so it causes a key error.

Check

```
if 'price' not in ads:
```

Instead.